# Python - Why does the Shapely method "contains" output true with the same polygon?

Tags: python, geometry, polygon, shapely

Let's say that I create the two fallowing polygons using shapely in python (they are represented in the figure):

```
poly1 = geometry.Polygon([[3,0], [1,0], [0, 1], [1,1]])
poly2 = geometry.Polygon([[0,0], [1,0], [0, 1], [1,1]])
```

[image: Representation of the two polygons]

I would like to know if they contain one another. To do that, I'm using the .contains() method built-in the shapely.geometry module.

So if I do `poly1.contains(poly2)` I get False, `poly2.contains(poly1)` I get False. But let's that I do `poly1.contains(poly1)` I get **True**. If I do the same with the second polygon `poly2.contains(poly2)`I get False.

Why do I keep getting true if I'm testing the same polygon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the shapely documentation:

> contains(a, b, **kwargs)
>
> Returns True if geometry B is completely inside geometry A.
>
> A contains B if no points of B lie in the exterior of A and at least
> one point of the interior of B lies in the interior of A.
>
> Note: following this definition, a geometry does not contain its
> boundary, but it does contain itself. See contains_properly for a
> version where a geometry does not contain itself.

From your picture, `poly1` is the blue shape and `poly2` is the orange shape. `poly1` has a point `(3,0)` which is exterior to `poly2` so `poly2.contains(poly1)` should return false. `poly2` contains a point `(0,0)` which is exterior to `poly1` so `poly1.contains(poly2)` should also return false.

As the documentation suggests, you should use the `contains_properly` method if you would like a shape not to contain itself... so `poly1.contains(poly1)` will return true, whereas `poly1.contains_properly(poly1)` will return false